# rendering html/css in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Are there any libraries for rendering HTML/CSS in Flash? Basically, I would like to be able to load in an external html file (nothing fancy, just some text, images and hyperlinks) and then render them to a Sprite.

Answer (score 1):

With Flash you can render a limited set of HTML within a *flash.text.**TextField*** via its htmlText property. Adobe AIR can utilize WebKit via *mx.controls.**HTML***.

Comment: Yeah I've had a go at this and it's pretty limited, especially with regards to control over flow and layout. I found this: http://motionandcolor.com/projects/htmlwrapper but the documentation is non-existent. I also found this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/as3htmlparser/files/ but it uses some Flex components so isn't an option for me. This (http://fcss.flashartofwar.com/) looks useful too, the demo video is funny in a sweary nerd kinda way. I'm surprised this sort of thing hasn't been more in demand - shame Adobe didn't build the WebKit engine in FP10.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my tutorial, Master HTML Formatted Text in Flash for a closer look at working with html/css in AS3:

http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/design/master-html-formatted-text-in-flash/